# Printing formatted R code

Tags: r, printing, tinn-r

I would like to adjust the print margins in tinn-R so the code stays on each line. I am trying to print some code but it wraps on to the next line and becomes less easy to read.
I have found the wrap text option but this simply chops off the end of the line. I use Rstudio but the print options are limited and my colleague suggested tinn-R which is better as it prints code formatted with colour.

I will happily take suggestions of other IDEs with good printing options.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,

The best option is decrease font size (the default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>) of the **editor** (or **Rterm**) to get the document fits within the print page.

In time, the Tinn-R project has its own discussion list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/tinn-r

All the best,

J.C.Faria

Comment: Two new buttons have been added to the Print preview interface to facilitate this task. 

This option will be available in the next stable version (3.0.3.5) of the project. 

The release candidate (RC) can be tested (today later) at this link: https://github.com/jcfaria/Tinn-R/tree/master/Tinn_R/install_setup/bin

Comment: The 3.0.3.5_RC was just now released on GitHub!

Comment: A bug related do final font size (printed file) in __Print preview__ interface was just now fixed.

Comment: __Tinn-R 3.0.3.5 stable__ was released tomorrow.